# iPhone Case Manufactuerer - Unlabelled but have logo

Tags: iphone, case

A family member has a really old iphone case that is pretty nice and I'm trying to find the company behind it. Unfortunately the case did not come with packaging (as far as we can remember), it was sold in the Apple Store at the time, and it doesn't have the company name on the case itself, just a logo:

[image]

I tried a google reverse image look up and it found nothing, so I'm hoping that someone here recognizes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out another way that this is Best Buy's house brand for phone accessories called **RocketFish**. Most of the phone items under this brand are now discontinued.